# Rsync using find command, delete original, replace original with symlink

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, rsync

I work for a graphics company, and our clients submit massive amounts of data. A single project folder can take up hundreds of gigabytes of space on our server. While space on my direct attached RAID is limited to 10TB, I have a 96TB storage server connected to my main server via iSCSI.

I'm not versed enough in BASH scripting to automate this process, but what I do manually is perform a find with this command:

```
find /disk -type d -name 09\ Client-Files | sed 's/ /\\ /g' > client-origs.txt
```

From this list I rsync the "09 Client-Files" directory to the storage server using:

```
rsync -avR /disk/Client-Jobs/1234\ Client/09\ Client-Files /iscsi
```

With the -R option it's copying the relative path to /iscsi.

After this the original "09 Client-Files" directory is deleted and a symlink pointing to its new location on the /iscsi volume.

What I'm shooting for is to use the found path as a variable to do everything at once. I'm really at a loss on how to proceed. I've been trying to educate myself on bash variables for days now — I can get them to work on simpler things but in this case I'm coming up empty. Can you help a brother out?

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at the `lndir` command? (may need to be installed separately)

It creates a shadow directory of symbolic links pointing to another directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that at once with find:

```
find /usr -type d -name My\ Files -exec rsync -avR '{}' /iscsi \;
```

For more info `man find`, right before the end there are several examples. Alternatively you can pipe the results using the `xargs` utility.

You should explore your manuals more througly, there is a lot of treasure to be found.

On a bash script you could also put:

```
export MIVARIABLE=$(find /usr -type d -name My\ files)
```

and then

```
for i in $MIVARIABLE ;do
   rsync -avR $i /iscsi;
done
```

But this has drawbacks among them if your results are very big, it may exceed bash maximum text space available for a variable , and if the retrieved names include spaces, some utilities may go crazy.

In a modern system the maximum size on a bash environment variable can be from 8kib to nearly 2MiB, if you put to much info on a variable you'll get a `Argument list too long` error.

So if you need to iterate over a file/directory list you better use find built-in functions or in cooperation with `xargs`. Read carefully their manuals and try some dry runs using `echo your_command_line` instead, so you gain appropiate experience and confidence with the utilities. Look for the `-print0` function on `find` as well as the `-0` command on `xargs` which are designed to avoid some problems with filenames with spaces and symbols in their names.

EDIT:
 `find` will handle white spaces correctly with the -exec operator:

```
find /usr -type d -name My\ Files -exec rsync -avR '{}' /iscsi \;  -exec rm -rf '{}'\;
```

would do what you need one after the other. I was pointing out options, so you could decide what was better suited to your needs, I did not meant to confuse you.

Edit2:

```
find /usr -type d -name 'My Files' -exec rsync -avR '{}' /iscsi \;  -exec rm -rf '{}'\;
```

funciona igual que el ejemplo de arriba. Cuando bash lee 'My Files' it takes the whole word togheter and does not treat the white spaces inside differently

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions RedComet. Your post was very helpful. I added a few things to your loop, `rm -r $i;` and `ln -s /iscsi/$i $i;`. The directories have spaces in them and the script won't parse the arguments, even if I pipe the variable to sed to escape the spaces. It works fine if I have no spaces in my test directories. Ideas?

Comment: This works, but when I add a third option on the find command to symlink back to the original parent directory, it will do the first one but none of the subsequent ones. `find /disk -type d -name "09 Client" -exec rsync -avR {} /iscsi \; -exec rm -r {} \; -exec ln -s /iscsi{} {} \;`

Comment: rm -r won't force deletion, depending on your shell variables, you must use rm -rf to ensure completion of the task. And ln will refuse to create a symbolic link over an existing directory, so fixing the second will fix the third

Comment: It behaves the same as before. If I don't have the `ln -s` part as the third -exec option, it does the rsync and removes all three original directories as expected. Adding symlinking to the end performs the first one properly but for the last two I get `find: /disk/Job2: No such file or directory`. Same error for /disk/Job3. In the bash script version, what's the deal with the variable not being able to handle spaces?

Comment: Are you enclosing all your {} in ' ?    As in  '{}'   ?   Bash use the white space as separator and special symbols are escaped=converted to something, Text enclosed on "" and  specially '' is not converted, and the white space inside is treated properly

Comment: Either quoting or double-quoting the brackets, the command acts the same. [Command without symlink.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/127728/rsync/no.link.txt) [Command with symlink.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/127728/rsync/with.link.txt) The strange thing is why would the command including the symlink work perfectly on the first directory it finds but not the others? Truly bizarre.

Comment: @Flex Brannigan: Since you don't have enough rep points we can't use the local chat box. I created a temporary irc channel "prshelp" at freenode.net. Can you join an irc channel ? This coments sections are not meant for talking, so it would be best to talk directly.